# GL_R32I TexImage2D not uploading correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I'm trying to create a tonemap fragment shader, to map values from `[0, someint]` to RGB values, but when I try to use GLints, the texture that gets rendered is all 0s.

Here's the relevant texture creation and binding code:

```
std::array<GLint , 25 > pixels;
int i=0;
float di = 255.0f / 25;
std::generate(pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), [&]{return di * i++;});

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, 5,5 ,0, 
GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, pixels.data());
```

and a fragment shader of:

```
#version 330

in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform isampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    ivec4 val = texture(tex, Texcoord);
    float ret = 0;
    if(val.r == 0)
    {
        ret = 1;
    }
    outColor = vec4(ret,0,0, 1.0);
}
```

Which is applied to a basic 2 triangles UV textured from `[0,1]`
The expected result would be one red corner and the rest black, but the entire square is red, signifying the entire texture is 0.

When I try the experiment with 
`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, 5, 5 ,0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, pixels.data());` and a `sampler2D`, the shader behaves as expected, but my values are clamped to `[0,1]`. Are the enums mismatched? `glGetError` returns no error, but it might be silently failing in some other way?

I'm using GLFW and OpenGL 3.3 on Ubuntu, not sure if `GL_R32I` is supported with that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to be anything but `GL_*_MIPMAP_*`? The initial value is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

If not then the texture won't work because you only have a single mipmap level defined. Thus the texture being incomplete.

By default the highest defined mipmap level is `1000`.
You can set it to `0` and that would *equally* work.

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0)
```

*The max level is a zero-based index.*

Comment: Ah! It was the filtering mode. Setting it from 'GL_LINEAR' to `GL_NEAREST` worked. Seems like `GL_INT` values can't be interpolated, makes sense.