# From C matrix to texture in modern OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl-3

### Problem

I am trying to write a simple program in C, using OpenGL, that would allow "drawing" a 2D C array (`int **`, 32-bit integers) according to a color palette.

For the moment (I am not there yet, far from it :) ) I'm learning how to send an array of 32-bits signed ints to the GPU and show it somehow.

I'm trying to do this in modern OpenGL.

My approach (bear with me as I just started learning these topics two days ago):

1. Geometry data consists of four vertices (`vertices`) for defining a rectangle based of two triangles (defining by picking the vertices using indices (`indices`)). The `vertices` data is also interleaved with 2D texture coordinates (for texture sampling in the shaders).
2. I do the generation and binding of VAO, VBO and EBO, to get the vertex data from RAM to VRAM.
3. Then, I create a 2D texture using `glTexImage2D()`, with internal format equal to `GL_R32I` as my C array is of type `int **`. I am not so sure about the `format` and `type` parameters, but I've set them to `GL_RED_INTEGER` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, respectively.
4. In the fragment shader I'm trying to "read" the original integers by doing something like `texture(texture1, TexCoord).r` but probably this isn't right... also tried to cast that red component to float: `(float) texture(texture1, TexCoord).r` but does not work either. Just to give you some reassurance that might code does somethings right, leaving only `FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1.0f);` in the fragment shader does show that colour, meaning I get a rectangle filling up the window with that color. So only when I start fiddling with the texture I get either a black screen or cyan RGB: `(0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`.

Note: My C array is named `plane`, and right now it is filled up with  a left block of `0` values and a right block of `1`s.

Right now, I'd be happy if I could hard code an if-statement inside the fragment shader that colored the `0`s and `1`s from the 32-bit `plane` into any two other colors. Then I think I could proceed to include a 1D texture with the color palette... as done [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/creating-a-retro-style-palette-swapping-effect-in-opengl).

### Code

#### `pixel.h`

```
#ifndef PIXEL_H
#define PIXEL_H

/* 
  To make sure there will be no header conflicts, you can define
  GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE before the GLFW header to explicitly disable
  inclusion of the development environment header. This also allows
  the two headers to be included in any order. 
*/
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <plane.h>
#include <utils.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#endif
```

#### `pixel.c`

```
#include <pixel.h>

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"
"out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"   TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n"
"}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"uniform isampler2D texture1;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"   //FragColor = vec4(texture(texture1, TexCoord).r, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main(void)
{
  
  // Window width and height.
  const unsigned int width = 20;
  const unsigned int height = 10;
  
  // Before you can use most GLFW functions, the library must be initialized.
  if (!glfwInit()) {
    printf("Could not initialise GLFW library!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  
  /*
   * By default, the OpenGL context GLFW creates may have any version.
   * You can require a minimum OpenGL version by setting the
   * GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR and GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR hints
   * before creation. If the required minimum version is not supported
   * on the machine, context (and window) creation fails.
   */
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  
  // Create a GLFW window.
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "pixel example", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window)
  {
    printf("Window or OpenGL context creation failed!\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  
  // Before you can use the OpenGL API, you must have a current OpenGL context.
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  
  /* 
   * If you are using an extension loader library to access modern OpenGL
   * then this is when to initialize it, as the loader needs a current
   * context to load from. This example uses glad, but the same rule applies
   * to all such libraries.
   */
  gladLoadGL();
  
  /*
   * Set a framebuffer size callback to update the viewport when
   * the window size changes.
   */
  glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, fb);
  
  /*
   * 
   * Data to be drawn.
   * 
   */
  int **plane = NewPlane(width, height);
  PLANE(width, height, if (i < width / 2) plane[i][j] = 0; else plane[i][j] = 1;)
  //plane[width/2][height/2] = 1;
  //PLANE(width, height, printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, plane[i][j]);)
  printf("size of int: %ld bytes\n", sizeof(int));
  
  // build and compile our shader program
  // ------------------------------------
  // vertex shader
  unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
  // check for shader compile errors
  int success;
  char infoLog[512];
  glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success)
  {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
  }
  // fragment shader
  unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  // check for shader compile errors
  glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success)
  {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
  printf("ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
  }
  // link shaders
  unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
  // check for linking errors
  glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success) {
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    printf("ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED%s\n", infoLog);
  }
  glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
  glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
  
  
  // float vertices[] = {
  //    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // top right
  //    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
  //   -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
  //   -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f  // top left 
  // };
  float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // texture coords
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
  };
  
  unsigned int indices[] = {
    // note that we start from 0!
    0, 1, 3, // first triangle
    1, 2, 3 // second triangle
  };
  
  unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  printf("VAO: %d\n", VAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  printf("VBO: %d\n", VBO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
  printf("EBO: %d\n", EBO);
  // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
  
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  
  // glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  // glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  // position attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  // texture coord attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  
  
  // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
  
  // remember: do NOT unbind the EBO while a VAO is active as the bound element buffer object IS stored in the VAO; keep the EBO bound.
  //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  
  // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
  // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
  glBindVertexArray(0); 
  
  // uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
  //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
  
  unsigned int texture;
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  if (plane) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, plane);
  }
  
  /*
   * 
   * Main loop
   * 
   */
  
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
  {
    
    // Check if Escape is pressed and signal to close the window.
    input(window);
    
    // The glClearColor function is a state-setting function
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    
    // The glClear is a state-using function in that it uses the
    // current state to retrieve the clearing color from.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // Rendering goes here.
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  
  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  
  glfwTerminate();
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

#### `plane.h`

```
#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PLANE(width, height, A) {int i,j,_ii,_jj;for(i=0,_ii=width;i<_ii;i++)for(j=0,_jj=height;j<_jj;j++){A};}

int **NewPlane(int, int);

#endif
```

#### `plane.c`

```
#include <plane.h>

int **NewPlane(int width,int height)
{
  int **a;
  int i,j;
  
  a = (int **)calloc((size_t)(width),sizeof(int *));
  if (a == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"NewPlane: error in memory allocation\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  a[0] = (int *)calloc((size_t)((width)*(height)),sizeof(int));
  if (a[0] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"NewPlane: error in memory allocation\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (i=1,j=width; i < j; i++)
    a[i] = a[i-1] + height;
  
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Open GL expects a contiguous 2D array. Either embed 2D array into 1D array  ( `int *a = calloc(height * width, sizeof *a)` ) or use a true 2D array with a pointer to VLA: ( `int (*a)[height] = calloc(width, sizeof *a);` )

Comment: Doesn't the line `a[0] = (int *)calloc((size_t)((width)*(height)),sizeof(int));` in `plane.c` ensure that I have a contiguous block of memory of `width`x`height` integers?

Comment: Yes, but  you must pass `glTexImage2D(..., plane[0]);` rather than `glTexImage2D(..., plane);`

Comment: I just tried that change :) but to no avail... `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, plane[0]);`

Comment: Code in the post is now updated, and also in my machine, I am using now always `plane[0]` in `glTexImage2D()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now, there were a few things that needed to be fixed.

1. As @Rabbid76 indicated, the conversion of the integral values in `value` (in the fragment shader code) to floating-point numbers within the range `[0, 1]` was an important change.
2. Also, as pointed out by @tstanisl, the data passed to `glTexImage2D()` needs to be contiguous in memory, so, in my case, changing the call to `glTexImage2D(..., plane[0])` was also important.
3. Finally, I was missing:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

as explained in [GL_R32I TexImage2D not uploading correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355491/gl-r32i-teximage2d-not-uploading-correctly).

Answer (score 1):

`texture` is an overloaded function. If you lookup a `isampler2D` with `texture` the type of the return value is `ivec4`:

```c
uniform isampler2D texture1;

void main() 
{
    int value = texture(texture1, TexCoord).r;

    // [...]
}
```

Since the internal data type is `GL_R32I`, the returned value is in the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. However, the color channel for the default framebuffer must be in the range [0.0, 1.0]. Therefore, you need to scale the integral value (`maxValue` should be the highest value in the texture):

```c
FragColor = vec4(float(value) / maxValue, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

---

Integral textures cannot be interpolated, therefore the minifying filter and magnification filter must to be `GL_NEAREST` (or `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST` in case of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`):

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Currently, the integral values in the variable `plane` (whose pointer is passed to `glTexImage2D()`) only contains `0`s or `1`s, so `maxValue` is `1`. But when I run your code I still get only cyan pixels, meaning that `value` is `0`, or very close to `0`. Perhaps my call of `glTexImage2D()` is not correct?

Comment: Code in the post is now updated, and also in my machine, I am using now always `FragColor = vec4(float(value) / maxValue, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` in the fragment shader.

Comment: @rmagn0 Do not apply the suggestions  from the answer to the question. That makes the answer useless.